# What to do if doctor says to eat non veg?

Tags: food, non-vegetarian

If someone is devotee or purely vegetarian, and that person is forced by doctor to eat non veg so that the disease or injury can cure. Is there any option that injury can cure and the religion policy not be disturbed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53574/discussion-on-question-by-rhythm-murgai-what-to-do-if-doctor-say-to-eat-non-veg).

Comment: what disease or injury requires you to eat non-veg ? does not make any sense. If you want protein, there is plenty in dal (pulses/legumes/beans)

Comment: First of all, the doctors say eat non-veg, as if there is no source of proteins but non-veg. It is very nonsensical. Actually it is nothing more than just an easy convention to say- "Eat non veg to get a protein", instead of listing you name of several veg things which are even more nutritious. As for non veg, it is often mentioned in AyurVeda to eat Non-veg in case of fractures, deep injuries, and extreme energy loss due to disease. But today doctors, even if we are buffing with health, say- O Lord! If you do not eat meat you would become weak, your bones will crack, you would die.

Comment: If you only need proteins, you don't need non-veg. There are many varieties of vegetarian food with plenty of protein in them. You can also take protein supplements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understand about Ayurveda, ***for medicinal purposes animal products can be used, especially if there is no alternative. They just should not be a part of regular diet.*** For reference, the following is a quote from [this article](http://easyayurveda.com/2010/07/15/is-ayurveda-totally-vegetarian/). *Note that I do not agree with the conclusion of the article*, as it says a non-vegetarian diet is acceptable based on non-vegetarian items having been included in some Ayurvedic treatments. The important point is that they are only included in treatments.

> Ayurveda is not totally vegetarian by any stretch of imagination.
>   Mamsarasa – the meat soup is explained in all the classical texts as
>   the best medicine for extreme emaciation. It reduces tiredness due to
>   Pitta imbalance (for example working under Sun for long hours), ideal
>   for those who do daily exercise, improves voice strength, skin
>   quality, immunity etc. (Reference: Charaka samhita Sutra sthana
>   27/312-325).
>
> [Aswagandhadi leham](http://easyayurveda.com/2009/11/10/ajaswagandhadi-leham/), also known as Ajaswagandhadi lehyam conains meat
>   as an ingredient, along with other herbs. [Some companies manufacture
>   it without meat as an ingredient]
>
> Varients of meat soup are explained as Vesavara in Bhavaprakasha,
>   another classical Ayurvedic text.
>
> Meat soup and other non veg diet has been prescribed along with
>   certain medications. Eg: Meat soup is a co -drink for the medicine
>   [Punarnvadyarishta](http://ayurmedinfo.com/2012/07/18/punarnavadyarishta-benefits-dosage-ingredients-side-effects/).

Taking care of health is quite important, as without that, in our current situation, it would be very difficult to pursue spirituality.

Answer (score 2):

Scriptures state that there is no sin in eating meat, when it is consumed for medicinal purposes.

**Brahma Purana 113.112**

> **In the following circumstances, even if one cats meat, one is not defiled:** if it is the remnant of offerings unto the Pitṛs, Devas
> etc. or if it is cooked in Śrāddha at the request of the brahmins and
> is sprinkled with holy water or **if it is taken as a medicine.**

**Markandeya Purana Canto XXXV**

> The remains of food at a śrāddha after the pitṛs and gods and other
> recipients have been satisfied may be eaten at the desire of the
> brāhmans. **A man who eats flesh that has been killed for the purpose of
> medicine is not defiled.**

**Padma purana III.56.31b-46**

> O best ones, Prajāpati Manu has said that these animals with five
> claws may be always eaten: alligator, tortoise, hare, rhinoceros,
> porcupine. He may also eat fish with scales, and the flesh of (the
> deer called) ruru after having presented them to deities and
> brāhmaṇas, and not otherwise. O best brāhmaṇas, so also (the flesh of)
> a peacock, a patridge, a pigeon, a cātaka, rhinoceros, a crane, a
> swan. Thus said Prajāpati (Manu). These fish, viz. (the glittering
> fish) śapharī, siṃhatuṇḍa, paṭhīna and rohita are directed as fit to
> be eaten. With a desire (to retain the status) as a twice-born he
> should eat the flesh of these after it is sprinkled over; even if he
> is about to lose his life he should duly use it. He should not at all
> eat flesh. He who eats what remains, is not smeared (with sin). **If
> he is weak, he should eat flesh as medicine, or by an order or for
> sacrificial purposes.** He, who would give up flesh when invited at a
> śrāddha or a rite in honour of a deity, goes to (i.e. lives) in hell
> for as many years as the number of hair of the beast.

In scripture, meat is recommended for various conditions e.g fracture patients.

**Garuda Purana I.171.10**

[image]

**Agni purana Chapter 279**

> 28b-30a. A person who has been injured (on the chest) should drink lac
> together with honey and milk. **Wasting diseases could be cured by
> eating the essence of meat and by protecting the digestive power. One
> should eat red śāli, nīvāra and kalama varieties of rice, cooked
> barley, meat, vegetables, natrum and śaṭī.**

> 33-34. Fried paddy, flours of fried barley, honey, **flesh roasted on a
> stick**, brinjal and gourd are drinks **for remedying vomitting.**
>
> l9b-21. **The juice of venison is commended as food for those
> suffering from pulmonary consumption.** Horse-gram, green-gram, black
> pepper etc. and dry radish compounded with venison or cakes or
> **bird’s flesh or compounded with curd and pomegranade juice, dressed with the juice of citron, honey, grapes and vyoṣa (dried ginger, long
> and black pepper) and cooked barley, wheat and śāli rice should be
> given as food to an asthma patient.**